# Prove that element of the set is divisible by k

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

How do you prove this theorem?

Theorem. For all positive integers n and k, some element of the set
{n, n + 1, n + 2, . . . , n + k − 1}
is divisible by k

Answer (score 1):

Observe that you have a complete set of representatives of equivalence classes modulo $k$?